# Javascript: How do I create element with id class and id which is some variable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Javascript:  How do I create element with id class and id  which is some variable?
Where I am not giving ID as some value but ID is equal to some  variable

Comment: You want to ```<a class="VariableName"></a>``` or ```<a class="VariableValue"></a>``` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I find this question confusing. Are you wanting to do <div id="class variablename"></div>? If so it's simply <div class="classname" id="idname"></div>

Answer (score 1):

```js
let id="theID", cls="MyClass"; // these are the "variables" ...

const div = document.createElement("div");
div.id=id; div.className=cls;div.textContent="This is the new div."
console.log(div.outerHTML);  // preview of the created markup
document.body.append(div)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do check DOM Manipulation of JavaScript methods:

`document.createElement('tag or div');`

`document.querySelector('id or class');`

`document.querySelector('id or class').appendChild(htmlElement);`